# Quadratic equation in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, equation, solver, quadratic

I made a quadratic equation solver with Javascript and HTML, but when I click the "calculate" button it just gets the "a" and "c" values and multiply then by -1.

I'm a beginner with Javascript, so I don't know much about object.

Here is the code:

```js
var a, b, c, xone, xtwo;

function getValues() {
  function getValues() {
    if (document.getElementById('signone').value == "+") {
      a = document.getElementById('vara').value;
    } else {
      a = document.getElementById('vara').value * (-1);
    }
    if (document.getElementById('signtwo').value == "+") {
      b = document.getElementById('varb').value;
    } else {
      b = document.getElementById('varb').value * (-1);
    }
    if (document.getElementById('signthree').value == "+") {
      c = document.getElementById('varc').value;
    } else {
      c = document.getElementById('varc').value * (-1);
    }
  }
}

function getSolution() {
  xone = ((-1 * b) + Math.sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
  xtwo = ((-1 * b) - Math.sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
}

function showSolution() {
  document.getElementById('showone').innerHTML = "x1 = " + xone;
  document.getElementById('showtwo').innerHTML = "x2 = " + xtwo;
}
```

```html
 <h1> Quadratic equation calculator </h1>
<p>This calculator is going to find the two values of <i>x</i> of the equation typed.</br>In order to use it properly, you have to fill all of the boxes</br>
  and click <q>ok</q>
</p>
</br>
<form>
  <select id="signone">
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
  </select>
  <input id="vara" type="text" name="firstvar" placeholder="type the coeficient a" />x2
  <select id="signtwo">
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
  </select>
  <input id="varb" type="text" name="secondvar" placeholder="type the coeficient b " />x
  <select id="signthree">
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
  </select>
  <input id="varc" type="text" name="thirdvar" placeholder="type the coeficient c" />=0
</form>
</br>
<button type="button" onclick="getValues();getSolution();showSolution();">Calculate</button>
<p id="showone">X1 =</p>
</br>
<p id="showtwo">X2 =</p>
```

Comment: `.value` returns a string, not a number.

Comment: Debug this code buddy. Test each part one peice at a time - output each steps result to console.log / alert it - and make sure its printing out what you want it to.

Comment: @IfTrue there is no such function. use `parseFloat`.

Comment: @DanielA.White Using a numeric string in an arithmetic expression will convert it to a number (except `+`, which does concatenation).

Comment: Your solution doesn't "show your work".  Teachers won't like that.  Try this page: http://eduexp.com/HomeworkQuadratic.asp

Answer (score 1):

When you get a value from a text input, that value is a **string** and is **not** a number in Javascript. This is why whenever an operation is done on it, it results in NaN. What is happening, for instance, is '3' * -1 which results in NaN because '3' is not a number. 3 is a number, but '3' (as a string) is not.

There is a simple solution to this. You can use `parseInt()` which converts a string value to an integer. However, it's probably better to use `parseFloat` in case a decimal number is entered. Proper code, for instance, would look like:

```
a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('vara').value) * (-1)
```

You are also breaking the DRP rule in many instances, "don't repeat yourself", as your code is very repetitive and could be more easily broken down with an iterating loop. Whenever you have a bunch of "if" statements like you have, it usually can be broken down in a loop. I'll give you the challenge of doing that.

As said below, (which I missed), you also have the function twice which is an issue.

Comment: A string will automatically be converted to a number if you operate on it with `-`, `/`, or `*`. So while it's a good idea to call `parseFloat` explicitly, it's not the problem in his code.

Comment: I agree. But style suggestions belong in comments, not the answer unless they directly relate to the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to pregreed through letters like you can do with numbers? example:
for(var p="a"; p < d; p++)

Comment: What does pregreed mean?

Comment: you see, i re-wrote the function getValues() as this:
function getValues(){
 var l=[a,b,c];
 for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
  l[i] = document.getElementById("var"+l[i]);
 }

Comment: Yes now you're thinking smart!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getValues()` isn't doing anything. You have an extra function definition inside the function, and you're never calling the inner function. Just define it once.

```js
var a, b, c, xone, xtwo;

function getValues() {
  if (document.getElementById('signone').value == "+") {
    a = document.getElementById('vara').value;
  } else {
    a = document.getElementById('vara').value * (-1);
  }
  if (document.getElementById('signtwo').value == "+") {
    b = document.getElementById('varb').value;
  } else {
    b = document.getElementById('varb').value * (-1);
  }
  if (document.getElementById('signthree').value == "+") {
    c = document.getElementById('varc').value;
  } else {
    c = document.getElementById('varc').value * (-1);
  }
}

function getSolution() {
  xone = ((-1 * b) + Math.sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
  xtwo = ((-1 * b) - Math.sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
}

function showSolution() {
  document.getElementById('showone').innerHTML = "x1 = " + xone;
  document.getElementById('showtwo').innerHTML = "x2 = " + xtwo;
}
```

```html
<h1> Quadratic equation calculator </h1>
<p>This calculator is going to find the two values of <i>x</i> of the equation typed.</br>In order to use it properly, you have to fill all of the boxes</br>
  and click <q>ok</q>
</p>
</br>
<form>
  <select id="signone">
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
  </select>
  <input id="vara" type="text" name="firstvar" placeholder="type the coeficient a" />x<sup>2</sup>
  <select id="signtwo">
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
  </select>
  <input id="varb" type="text" name="secondvar" placeholder="type the coeficient b " />x
  <select id="signthree">
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
  </select>
  <input id="varc" type="text" name="thirdvar" placeholder="type the coeficient c" />=0
</form>
</br>
<button type="button" onclick="getValues();getSolution();showSolution();">Calculate</button>
<p id="showone">X1 =</p>
</br>
<p id="showtwo">X2 =</p>
```